# How Do I Ensure a Candidate Latin Square Is a Valid Damm Operation Table

Tags: algorithm, scala, check-digit

I am attempting to write a function in Scala that takes a valid [Latin Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square) as input and then returns a `Boolean` value indicating whether the input Latin Square is a valid instance of an operation-table for the [Damm Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damm_algorithm), or not. The Damm Algorithm appears to be of the ["Check digit"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_digit) class of error detection mechanisms.

The desired function is an implementation of the implication described in the [Design section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damm_algorithm#Design) of the Wikipedia article for the [Damm Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damm_algorithm). The implication is captured by the assertion of:

> a weak totally anti-symmetric quasigroup with the property x ∗ x = 0

I'm insufficient in both the math skills to properly read and interpret Damm's paper, and then having enough German (the language within which the paper was written) reading skills to be able to confidently interpret how I would encode a correct validation function.

Given the following function definition:

```scala
def validate(latinSquare: List[List[Int]]): Boolean =
  ???
```

With what would I replace the `???`?

Within the paper, a single instance of a valid 10x10 Latin Square is provided. It is [reproduced within the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damm_algorithm#Example) and looks like this:

```
 |0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
-+-------------------
0|0 3 1 7 5 9 8 6 4 2
1|7 0 9 2 1 5 4 8 6 3
2|4 2 0 6 8 7 1 3 5 9
3|1 7 5 0 9 8 3 4 2 6
4|6 1 2 3 0 4 5 9 7 8
5|3 6 7 4 2 0 9 5 8 1
6|5 8 6 9 7 2 0 1 3 4
7|8 9 4 5 3 6 2 0 1 7
8|9 4 3 8 6 1 7 2 0 5
9|2 5 8 1 4 3 6 7 9 0
```

I can see [there are others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29484392/how-to-implement-the-damm-algorithm-for-checksums-and-redundancy) who have [sought an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747247/alternative-base-table-for-damm-algorithm) to this. However, no one has yet provided a requested **code-based** valid Latin Square solution.

I have coded up a generic Latin Square generator, but need the above validation function which will serve as the filter to eliminate each candidate Latin Square that does not meet the necessary condition(s) of the above implication.

Comment: This isn't a mathematics site either !

Comment: @Tim LOL! Okay. I got what I was looking for with the Python answer provided by David Eisenstat. I will be posting the Scala version of the answer later today. And then later, I will provide the general solution on the threads I found requesting it. IOW, I will be producing and providing far more value than I consumed by asking this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In functional programming terms, the checksum algorithm is `foldLeft` with a carefully chosen binary operation. The requirements for this binary operation, in English:

- In every two-digit input, if we change one of the digits, then the checksum changes (Latin square…);
- In every three-digit input, if the latter two digits are distinct and we swap them, then the checksum changes (…with weak total antisymmetry);
- The Latin square has zeros on the diagonal.

In Python 3:

```
def validate(latinSquare):
    Q = range(len(latinSquare))
    return all(
        x == y
        for c in Q
        for x in Q
        for y in Q
        if latinSquare[latinSquare[c][x]][y] == latinSquare[latinSquare[c][y]][x]
    ) and all(latinSquare[x][x] == 0 for x in Q)


print(
    validate(
        [
            [0, 3, 1, 7, 5, 9, 8, 6, 4, 2],
            [7, 0, 9, 2, 1, 5, 4, 8, 6, 3],
            [4, 2, 0, 6, 8, 7, 1, 3, 5, 9],
            [1, 7, 5, 0, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 6],
            [6, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 9, 7, 8],
            [3, 6, 7, 4, 2, 0, 9, 5, 8, 1],
            [5, 8, 6, 9, 7, 2, 0, 1, 3, 4],
            [8, 9, 4, 5, 3, 6, 2, 0, 1, 7],
            [9, 4, 3, 8, 6, 1, 7, 2, 0, 5],
            [2, 5, 8, 1, 4, 3, 6, 7, 9, 0],
        ]
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a conversion into Scala of the [Python 3 Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72342123/501113) that was provided by David Eisenstat's answer.

[View in Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/D0fRRQBeTzCAKgXCp4K0Zg):

```scala
def isValidDammOperationTable(validLatinSquare: List[List[Int]]): Boolean = {
  val indices = validLatinSquare.indices.toList
  (
        indices.forall(index => validLatinSquare(index)(index) == 0)
    &&  indices.forall(
          c =>
            indices.forall(
              x =>
                indices.forall(
                  y =>
                        (validLatinSquare(validLatinSquare(c)(x))(y) != validLatinSquare(validLatinSquare(c)(y))(x))
                    ||  (x == y)
                )
            )
        )
  )
}

val exampleLatinSquareX10: List[List[Int]] =
  List(
      List(0, 3, 1, 7, 5, 9, 8, 6, 4, 2)
    , List(7, 0, 9, 2, 1, 5, 4, 8, 6, 3)
    , List(4, 2, 0, 6, 8, 7, 1, 3, 5, 9)
    , List(1, 7, 5, 0, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 6)
    , List(6, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 9, 7, 8)
    , List(3, 6, 7, 4, 2, 0, 9, 5, 8, 1)
    , List(5, 8, 6, 9, 7, 2, 0, 1, 3, 4)
    , List(8, 9, 4, 5, 3, 6, 2, 0, 1, 7)
    , List(9, 4, 3, 8, 6, 1, 7, 2, 0, 5)
    , List(2, 5, 8, 1, 4, 3, 6, 7, 9, 0)
  )

println(isValidDammOperationTable(exampleLatinSquareX10)) //prints "true"
```